# FXML variable reference is null

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, fxml, fxmlloader

So I'm learning how to use FXMl and I have run into yet another problem with getting a reference to an object by fx:id at runtime, I get a null pointer exception with the following code.

```xml
  <TableView fx:id="productTable" layoutX="92.0" layoutY="319.0" prefHeight="97.0" prefWidth="363.0" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.columnSpan="5" GridPane.rowIndex="3" GridPane.rowSpan="2">
     <columns>
        <TableColumn prefWidth="98.0" text="Product ID" fx:id="productID"/>
        <TableColumn prefWidth="110.0" text="Product Name" fx:id="productName"/>
        <TableColumn prefWidth="131.0" text="Inventory Level" fx:id="productInventoryLevel"/>
        <TableColumn prefWidth="128.0" text="Price per Unit" fx:id="productPrice"/>
     </columns>
  </TableView>
```

```
//Controller.java
@FXML private TableView<Product> productTable;
@FXML private TableColumn<Product, String> productID;
@FXML private TableColumn<Product, String>  productPrice;
@FXML private TableColumn<Product, String>  productName;
@FXML private TableColumn<Product, String>  productInventoryLevel;

//Product properties declared the same as https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm#
private ObservableList<Product> productData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Product(0, "Wheel", 100.99, 4, 0, 1), 
        new Product(1, "Seat", 50.0, 4, 0, 1));

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
    System.out.println("Product ID factories");

    productID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("productID"));
    productPrice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("productPrice"));
    productInventoryLevel.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("productInventoryLevel"));
    productName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("productName"));
     productTable.setItems(productData);

      System.out.println("Set items");

}
```

As you can see I declare the `@FXML` tag, then the variable by `fx:id` and right after my first print statement I get a runtime nullpointer exception on the `productID`

EDIT:
The above code currently runs without error but will only populate the "productID" section of my table.

Comment: Also after testing if I attempt to call any methods from "productTable" after declaring @FXML private TableView productTable, I get a null reference to that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, it's not sure what the `UI` class extends. It does look like it extended from `Application`, and is the starting class of the whole application.

Making my best guess, I would say there are two possible reasons why you did this:

1. You copied from the first (`Application` extending) class. This is unlikely since you said you had a `NullPointerException`, unless you manually called `start()`.
2. This "controller" class *is* indeed the starting class, and you intended to let it be the controller class for `FXMLDocument.fxml`. This seems to be the likely case here.

Assuming that you want the `Application` extending class to be a controller, you need to create an instance of `FXMLLoader`, instead of using the static method `FXMLLoader.load()`.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
loader.setController(this); // You need to set this instance as the controller.
Parent root = loader.load();
// Other stuff you need to do
productID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("productID"));
```

This will set the currently running instance of `UI` as the controller for `FXMLDocument.fxml`.

There are several points to take note.

1. Do not use `fx:controller` in FXML, or create a new instance of `UI` (and setting it) as an alternative. You *must* provide the current instance to the `FXMLLoader`.
2. All fields annotated via `@FXML` will only be injected (i.e. non-null) after `FXMLLoader.load()` has been called, or in `initialize()` method. If you try to call `productID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("productID"));`, you may get a `NullPointerException`, depending on the sequence of your codes.

Lastly, you do have an option of making another class the controller of the FXML file. In fact, most people would do that as that is the purpose of MVC (which is the architecture JavaFX uses). Of course, all injected fields and initialization would also move to the new controller class. Also remember that injected fields are `null` in constructor - so initialize in `initialize()` of the new controller class.

Comment: So for reference I'm trying to adapt this code https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm# to using an FXML sheet. After I moved what you stated into my controller class I managed to make it run however I still am only seeing the first column being populated by my observable list, I will edit my above post to show you what I mean.